# Passing reference of the current object in a class member function in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

Just like the `this` pointer is used to pass the pointer to the current object, how do I pass reference to the current object ?

```
class UseMe
{
    public:
         UseMe_funcReference(base&);
         UseMe_FuncPointer(base *)

}

class base{
..........
}
class Abc:public base
{
public:
   friend UseMe;
   UseMe innerObj;
   Func1()
   {
       (this->innerObj).UseMe_funcPointer(this); // This passes pointer to current object
       (this->innerObj).UseMe_funcReference(HOW_TO_PASS_REFERENCE_TO_CURRENT_OBJECT);
   }
}
```

Comment: `*this` is a reference to the current object... And I'm not sure I understood the question...

Comment: @StoryTeller: No, it isn't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Yeah, it's an expression with a certain value category, could be bound to a reference... Doesn't change the fact I'm not sure any of this answers the OP's query.

Comment: Shame you wrote a proposed solution in the comments where it cannot be downvoted for brazen technical inaccuracy and misinformation, @Story! And why do you think it doesn't answer the OP's query?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Why give me the benefit of the doubt? I was surely spreading disinformation to confuse the OP (and future readers, let us not forget), rather than speaking colloquially to understand what they meant. Good on you for setting things straight.

Comment: _"`*this` is a reference to the current object"_ Simple misinformation. Period

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Yup, the *"Period"* is surely proof of intent to deceive. *(shurg)*. I'll be off.

Answer (score 6):

You don't notate pass-by-reference that at the *call site*, there you use exactly the same syntax as a regular pass-by-value.

In the actual function, you use `&` to denote that the parameter is passed by reference. For example consider the function `foo` that takes a `bar` as a reference:

```
void foo(bar& reference);
```

Then you could use `foo(*this)` at the call site, if `this` is a `bar*` (or related) type.

Comment: Have an upvote. Thanks for pointing out that we never "pass by reference" so much as "take by reference"

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `*this`, as when returning a reference to self from an assignment operator.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a pointer to the current object.

`*this` is a name for the current object.

Contrary to what some of the other people have said here, it is *not* a reference (dereferencing a `T*` gives you an lvalue `T`), but you can bind a reference to it just as you would elsewhere.

**tl;dr: dereference it, as you would any other pointer**